# How to match different content on a page according to which user is logged-in?

Tags: django, authentication

I just started using django and I have some problems understanding how to use auth on my web app. So, basically, what I cannot understand how to implement is displaying different content on my page for each user

My app is an online editor that each user can use to write their code and have it stored. I have implemented the sign up/sign in and what I need to do now is to have a different filesystem for each user and display it appropriately.

I don't know why I can't find this answer anywhere but I am really overwhelmed with this problem and I have done zero progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have **2** easy ways to do this:

**1 - Inside template**

**2 - Inside Views**

Which to prefer when:

**Template** - When you have less content to be segregated then go with template way.
How to do that?

```
 `{% if user.is_superuser %}


     <some html> 
     #Your html for Superuser  

     #you can also include a another html file
     {% include "App_name/Superuser_view.html" %}


  {% else %}

     <some html>
     #Your html for Staff or whoever  

     #you can also include a another html file
     {% include "blazon/employee_view.html" %}  


  {% endif %}`
```

---

**Inside Views :** when you need to render lot of html differences among the user types then go with this method.

```
def view(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser():
        #your View Function & return it individually 

    elif request.user.is_admin():
        #your View Function

    else request.user.is_staff():
        #your View Function
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't want to display different content on each user type but on each user. I mean that it doesn't matter if he is staff or admin etc. but every account has a different filesystem that I want to display.

Comment: You need to extend user table then and have a unique identifier for each user.

Answer (score 0):

You can check what permissions does a user have and implement different logic in view for different types of users:

```
def some_view(request):
    if request.user.is_admin:
        # logic for Admin users
    elif request.user.is_staff:
        # logic for Staff only
    else:
        # logic for all other users
```

If you want to implement your custom permissions you can check [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions).

Comment: It's just that for all the other users I want to display different things for each.